# How to stop tinyproxy from using "Proxy-Connection" header

Tags: connection, http-headers, tinyproxy

I just setup tinyproxy for the first time, and I'm trying to make it mimic a normal connection as closely as possible.  I already disabled the `Via` header, but I'm not sure how to change the `Proxy-Connection:keep-alive` header.  I would like for it to simply be `Connection:keep-alive`.  I understand that `Proxy-Connection` is not only revealing of proxy usage, but unnecessary according to sites like [this](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/web-proxy-connection-header.html).

To be honest, I'm not sure exactly what party is sending this header, whether it's my local machine or the remote tinyproxy.  How would one either verify this and/or change this in the configuration?

**Edit:**

I'm seeing the header when I use the proxy while browsing in Chrome.  Inspecting the request headers in chrome reveals:

[image: Headers while browsing in Chrome]

Comment: The so-called Proxy-Connection header was never actually defined in any HTTP related RFC, so it really should not be appearing anywhere. There's no way for anyone to know what it's supposed to mean, and the _actual_ proxy related headers are well documented.

Comment: I understand that it shouldn't be appearing anywhere, but it is.  It is present in request headers when I inspect them in browser dev-tools.  Are you saying that no one ever checks for it?

Comment: A quick look at the tinyproxy source code shows that _it strips out this header if present_, and the changelog says it has done so since... 2002. Where exactly are you seeing this header appear?

Comment: Just added some information in the question

Comment: That's rather bizarre. I'd start by disabling all those extensions to see if one of them is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Tinyproxy is not adding the Proxy-Connection header.
It is the client who must be adding it.

Tinyproxy should even remove this header (and a few others) from the request (or response) before sending it on to the server (or client).

You could verify this by sniffing the traffic between the proxy and server (wireshark...) and looking at the request packets as going from proxy to server.